# How do I understand this index matrix in R

Tags: r

Here I have a

```
x <- array(1:20, dim=c(4,5))
x
[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  1 5 9 13 17
[2,]  2 6 10 14 18
[3,]  3 7 11 15 19
[4,]  4 8 12 16 20
```

I also have a index array

```
i <- array(c(1:3,3:1), dim=c(3,2))
[,1] [,2]
[1,] 1 3
[2,] 2 2
[3,] 3 1
```

Then

```
x[i]
```

will extract X[1,3], X[2,2] and X[3,1]

However, what if I have

```
i <- array(c(1:3,3:1), dim=c(2,3))
```

The output is

```
x[i]
[1] 1 2 3 3 2 1
```

How can I understand this result?

Comment: If the matrix i does not have exactly two columns then x[i] will go through every element in i column by column.  If you do x[i[]] for the two column case will return this same result.

Comment: @R.Schifini - that's not strictly true - if the array has `3` or even `n` dimensions, you can pass a `3` or `n` column matrix as the index. But, yep, it seems if you pass a higher number of columns in it reverts to indexing one value at a time.

Comment: A matrix is a vector with dimensions.  So, in this case as there are more columns than the row/column indexing matrix, it will be a vector for 'i' and so, each element is a index that select the corresponding value from 'x' i.e. 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1 are basically the values of 'x' in the corresponding position.  If you change 'x', you will understand it. i.e. `x <- array(20:1, dim = c(4,5))
 x[i]#[1] 20 19 18 18 19 20`  It is only a coincidence that you are getting the output of `x[i]` as `i` in that example.

Comment: @akrun - admittedly, I can't find where this is documented anywhere easily, so it's a pretty good question to my mind.

Comment: The downvote is a bit harsh no? The example is clearly specified, and this is as far as I can tell an undocumented feature that subsetting with a matrix  where `ncol(i) > length(dim(x))` reverts to vector-like subsetting.